# Is there any way to combine PNGs as a Quicktime-compatible MP4 from FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg, quicktime

Is there any way to get combine PNGs as a Quicktime-compatible MP4 from FFMPEG?

I'm using this command currently:

```
ffmpeg -i frame%03d.png -pix_fmt yuv420p  output.mp4
```

This is the video works fine in VLC and can be uploaded to Youtube/Vimeo/Facebook fine but Quicktime complains that it "cannot be opened":
[image]

A few questions (e.g. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/166553/why-wont-video-from-ffmpeg-show-in-quicktime-imovie-or-quick-preview)  about this at various sources, but none of the answers seem to work and they all seem to boil to down to some variant of "use yuv420p" or a couple of other flags.  None of which seems to work.  Apparently it may have changed in later (post-Yosemite) versions of MacOS?

So what (if anything) is the magic incantation that make this work with later versions of Quicktime?

Thanks all

ffprobe output below FYI:

```
ffprobe version 4.2.2 Copyright (c) 2007-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.2.2_2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/Users/xxx/Downloads/output (14).mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
  Duration: 00:00:02.72, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 677 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv444p, 1714x1630, 672 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
```

Comment: Looks like your `-pix_fmt yuv420p` got ignored. The command itself looks fine. The complete log from the command would be helpful to narrow down the issue.